# How does grooveshark.com detect mobile users?

Tags: html, redirect, mobile

When you visit http://grooveshark.com/ with a smartphone, you're redirected to http://html5.grooveshark.com/. I was wondering if anyone knows how they do this. Can anyone tell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Requests sent from a browser to a website contain the User Agent string in a header. See http://www.useragentstring.com/

This likely gets compared to a maintained list of known mobile devices.

Comment: Is that the most fool proof way for detecting mobile users?

Comment: It's pretty sound, yes. There are browser plugins and mobile apps to fake your user agent, but 99% of the time it'll be accurate. What server side technology are you using? There will probably be some sort of library that exists to check for mobile already.